# Laravel Eloquent: take() in with() not loading expected number of related records

Tags: php, laravel, database, eloquent

I'm facing an issue with a Laravel Eloquent query where I'm trying to eager load related records with a limit using the `take()` method within the `with()` method. However, the query is not loading the expected number of related records.

The problem I'm encountering is that this code only retrieves the first 6 articles for the first category, and it does not load up to 6 articles for each category, even though there are hundreds of articles for each category.

**Code Sample:**

I have two Eloquent models: `Category` and `Article`. Each `Category` has many `Article` records, and I want to load up to 6 articles for each category. Here's the code I'm using:

```
$categories = Category::with(['articles' => function ($query) {
    $query->take(6);
}])->get()->toArray();
```

**Category.php**

```
 public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }
```

**What I've Checked:**

- I've verified that each category has more than 6 articles associated with it.
- I've made sure that there are no other constraints or filters applied to the result set in my code.
- The database schema appears to have the correct relationships defined.

**Expected Outcome:**

I expect the query to load up to 6 articles for each category, not just the first 6 articles for the first category.

**Laravel version: 10.0**

Comment: but that not what I want, applying that separately will lead to performance issue .. if I have 100 of category, that mean it will do 100 of calls .

Comment: why not start from the articles and eager load their categories?

Comment: Yep, you were right, my test case was not correct. This isn't a built in feature of eloquent. However I did find a package that solves this by extending the eloquent builder, that hopefully helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `eloquent-eager-limit` https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

`composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"`

include `HasEagerLimit` trait in both models.

```php
class Category extends Model
{
  use HasEagerLimit;
...

class Article extends Model
{
  use HasEagerLimit;
...
```

use limit on your eager loading as usual.

```php
$categories = Category::query()
  ->with(['articles' => fn($query) => $query->limit(6)])
  ->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: The library did work , the generated query is  a bit weird  , the perfromance didn't change much but for sure this is better and do the thing I was looking for .. both query ( get then all and by using the library are returning 6 seconds ) .. I'm doing on on 500K row test example

Comment: Look like no one else has more solutions for this problem, finding it werid that laravel doesn't support such a thing, I'm going to mark this as the best answer , thanks for sharing